# two infragistics controls on same line

Tags: asp.net, html, rendering, infragistics

My ASPX code is:

```
<span>                        
  <igsch:WebDateChooser ID="ContractPeriod2Start" runat="server" 
     NullDateLabel="" Editable="True" EnableAppStyling="True">
  </igsch:WebDateChooser>
  <igsch:WebDateChooser ID="ContractPeriod2End" runat="server" 
     NullDateLabel="" Editable="True" EnableAppStyling="True">
  </igsch:WebDateChooser>
  <span><a href="#">Remove</a></span>
</span>
```

I want it to render that top-level span all in the same line/row.  However infragistics renders that out into a bunch of tables and divs, some greyed out in firebug

```
<span>

    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <table ... >...</table>
    <div>...</div>

    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <table ... ></table>
    <div ... ></div>

    <span><a href="#">Remove</a></span>
</span>
```

which renders out into 3 lines (one for each of two IG controls, one for my Remove span)

How do I make all this generated HTML into the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the third party control has no way to control the output, the quickest idea I can come up with is to wrap everything in a table.  You still would not be controlling the output of each individual control, but you would force the three elements into one line.

So, not pretty, but:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><!-- First igsch control here --></td>
        <td><!-- Second igsch control here --></td>
        <td><span><a href="#">Remove</a></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is probably some way to write an adapter to generate different html, such as the [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CssAdapters/), but that would take a much greater effort.

Comment: +1 because it will work, but be wary that using tables will make people call you "ghetto".